# MySQLi prepared insert statement fails

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am updating my PHP to use `mysqli::` instead of `mysql_*` and I have run into an issue with `INSERT` statements. I have the following statement:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`a`, `b`, `c`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $a, $b, "0");
$stmt->execute();
```

I have checked `$stmt` and it is a proper `mysqli_stmt` object. It is prepared properly, but for some reason, the statement won't execute. I just get a 500 error from my server.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

I've determined that the issue is coming from the `bind_param` method.

**Edit 2**

Okay, so the error PHP is giving me is this:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 4 by reference in...

This points to the line of bind_param

Comment: At the moment you're missing the error message from your server's error log.

Comment: @MikeW I don't have access to my server's error logs. Is there a way to determine this directly in PHP? I know that `$oid` is 51760 and $cid is like 10170. I also have a select statement before this that is working properly, so I don't know why this one isn't.

Comment: I contacted my provider and got access to the log. Just one sec and I'll find it.

Comment: I sugesst you add following code to the beginning of your php file, and try to see if you get any errors. `<?php
ini_set("display_errors","1");
if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.0.0", ">")==1) {
 ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL | E_STRICT);
} else {
 ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
};
?>`

Comment: I put in the error checking lines and got the error in **Edit 2** in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a constant to bind_param. Put the value in a variable first:

```
$status = "0";
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $oid, $cid, $status);
$stmt->execute();
```